# UbuntuMATE 20.04 LTS and BFS Scheduler

Tags: gui, performance

Can anybody tell me if UbuntuMATE has already incorporated the **BFS Scheduler** patch components highly praised by Linus in the article [**here**](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_2637_video&num=1) ?

*I realize that reference is from 2010*, but I am trying to understand why my Desktop is sluggish, when I am not doing any "heavy" work (no compiling, no typesetting, no database, no spreadsheets, no dashboards).  I only have my browser with 2 or 3 Gvim windows, a console window, 2 Caja file cabinet open and that is all.

```
root@OasisMega1:/DB001_F2# myDf.sh

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda3       192G   19G  164G  11% /

/dev/sda7       289G  261G   14G  96% /DB001_F2 
/dev/sda8       289G  252G   23G  92% /DB001_F3
/dev/sda9       289G  226G   49G  83% /DB001_F4
/dev/sda12      193G   32G  151G  18% /DB001_F5
/dev/sda13      193G  149G   34G  82% /DB001_F6
/dev/sda14      289G  158G  117G  58% /DB001_F7
/dev/sda4        92G   35G   53G  40% /DB001_F8

/dev/sdc2       108G  7.8G   95G   8% /site/DB004_F1

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

I have 4G of RAM.
As for swap,

```
root@OasisMega1:/DB001_F2# swapon
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sdc1 partition   2G 2.3M    1
```

I want to underline that the swap is on a physically different device, which is not my system or boot disk.

I've seen references to changes to swappiness but anything I've tried has made things worse, so I put the value back to the Distro default.

Any suggestions?

Other info:

```
 COMMAND: 'inxi -c 0 -f -xxx 2>&1 | tail --lines=+3'
           bogomips: 20870 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/2600 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 
           4: 800 
           Flags: 3dnow 3dnowext 3dnowprefetch abm apic clflush cmov cmp_legacy 
           constant_tsc cpuid cr8_legacy cx16 cx8 de extapic extd_apicid fpu fxsr 
           fxsr_opt ht hw_pstate ibs lahf_lm lbrv lm mca mce misalignsse mmx mmxext 
           monitor msr mtrr nonstop_tsc nopl npt nrip_save nx osvw pae pat pdpe1gb pge 
           pni popcnt pse pse36 rdtscp rep_good sep skinit sse sse2 sse4a svm svm_lock 
           syscall tsc vme vmmcall wdt

 COMMAND: 'inxi -y 255 -c 0 -G -xxx'
Graphics:  Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RS780D [Radeon HD 3300] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: radeon v: kernel bus ID: 01:05.0 chip ID: 1002:9614 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: ati,radeon unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa compositor: marco v: 1.24.0 resolution: 1440x900~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: AMD RS780 (DRM 2.50.0 / 5.4.0-88-generic LLVM 12.0.0) v: 3.3 Mesa 21.0.3 compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes
```

Comment: It's not likely to be the kernel scheduler. It's not likely to be your swap. My 21.10 Desktop, on quite low-spec hardware, only 4GB of RAM and no video card (onboard Intel CPU video), is fast and responsive.

Comment: Those patches are either in current kernels, or have been abandoned as the kernel the patch for is no longer supported, used etc.  *I too think your issue is something else*.